# Возможности андроид-приложений

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, интересуют такие вопросы:

- Есть ли возможность у
     андроид-приложения определить,
     запущено ли оно на виртуальной машине
     (с рутом и без)? Если да - то какие
     соответствующие разрешения будут
     показаны при установке этого
     приложения?
- Может ли приложение
     получить список других активных
     приложений и какие соответствующие
     разрешения будут показаны при
     установке этого приложения?

Comment: 1. Достоверно и однозначно определить нельзя.     
2. Может. Это очень легко найти в гугле, на пример, по запросу [android get running applications list][1] (доп. разрешений приложению для этого не требуется)


  [1]: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=android+get+running+applications+list&oq=android+get+running+app&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.7711j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @metalurgus, потребуется разрешение `GET_TASKS`.